# How do I use a provisioning profile that's not on my account to distribute an application?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to sign an application using a different account from the one I usually use. I have their certificates as well as a `.mobileprovision` file that has all the devices on it. I've imported the `.p12` file, the `ios_distribution.cer` file, and the `.mobileprovision` file on to my computer.

I've also changed the settings under `Code Signing => Provisioning Profile` to use their certificate and provisioning profile. But when I `Archive` the application, and then hit `Distribute`, I'm presented with the choice of more provisioning profiles from my account.

How do I use their provisioning profile? And what's the difference between Code Signing => Provisioning Profile and the Provisioning Profile on Export?

Comment: They need to add you as a member of their developer account, and then you can do it properly the same way as you would with your own account. Note that a single Apple ID/Developer can be attached to multiple iOS store developer accounts. When you log in with your username/password, it will ask you which account to use. Alternatively, email the unsigned *.ipa file to them, and they can sign/submit it to the app store (I'm not sure how to do this, but it can be done).

Comment: So even though I have their certificate and their provisioning profile, I can't use it without being added to their account? And I'm still not sure what the difference is between Code Signing => Provisioning Profile and the Provisioning Profile on Export?

Comment: What type of distribution are you trying to do? App Store or Ad Hoc?

Comment: For App Store distribution you definitely need to log into the relevant section of Apple's website. For Ad Hoc distribution I don't think it's necessary, but you might have to jump through hoops. Why are you trying to avoid being a member of the team on the developer account?

Comment: If you really don't want to be a member of the team, you can always distribute as an "Xcode Archive" which doesn't involve provisioning at all. Then a member of the team can load the archive into Xcode's Organizer and do the distribution themselves. You don't need to give them the source code for the app.

Comment: Ad Hoc. If we have contractors that we don't want to add to the account (or if we're developing for someone who doesn't want to add us to the account), but still want to allow them to build an IPA file for distribution. Is the only way really to add someone to the account, even though I have the certificate and provisioning profile? It would seem that I have all the pieces needed to sign it.

Comment: If you are not willing to give someone an account you *abso****inglutely* should not be giving them the p12 certificate. For gods sake man, that is the part you need to protect most of all. It is technically possible to do an Ad-Hoc deployment without having an account, but I think you'll have to use the command line rather than Xcode.app. But I don't know how. Another option you have is to setup a continuous integration server (https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/XcodeCIGuide) which will check your source code repository every few seconds, and create an IPA if the code changes.

Comment: A tool that may interest you is called iResign.  It is a small OS X tool that allows you to sign an unsigned IPA, or resign a signed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's possible, I just needed to change the `Bundle Identifier` to match the provisioning profile I was given.